# Detecting IP Multicast Failure in Flash

Tags: flash, stream, adobe, multicast

I have implemented player with IP Multicast using Adobe flash media server http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/devguide/WS7812b00092aae0dc-2829dcd012a54a3ed1a-8000.html . I have multiple multicast servers , so if one multicast server fails I want to rollover to another server . In case of IP Multicast a connection to server is never made so how can I detect a failure in that case inside flash player ?

Thanks

Comment: Do the Flash clients that connect to your multicast servers use a `NetConnection` and/or a `NetStream`? These classes dispatch `NetStatusEvent`'s which has an [info](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/NetStatusEvent.html#info) property which will give you status/error information. They're very useful when streaming, and so I'd imagine they would be just as useful in the multicast scenario.

Comment: @SunilD. What I see from this post http://forums.adobe.com/message/4992112 "IP Multicast uses routers to send data to a specified IP address. Even if no flash media server is there on the network, you will get NetConnection.Connect.Success." . So in the middle of stream if AMS fails there is no way to detect that situation .

Comment: That's really interesting. The next thing I would try is to deduce that whether playback has started or not. For example, there are a handful of properties of the [NetStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html) that would be useful for this: `info`, `multicastInfo`, `bytesLoaded`, etc. I've done this successfully to determine if a user's webcam was successfully (or stopped) publishing it's feed over a `NetStream`. You might have to do some testing to determine, from these properties, what indicates a failure scenario.

Comment: @SunilD. We have implemented rollback if stream fails on inital connection , But if it fails in between there was no way to detect it . Your point will help though , I am using multicastInfo in player , logging it bytes received every 3 seconds , may be I will check if it was updated since last time and not than rollover to another streaming server . Thanks !

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did w/detecting when the video suddenly stops publishing from the camera. Note, that you will probably have to set a threshold on the number of bytes (like say 4KB/second) , as we found in our case that even a failed camera stream was sending a little bit of data). Not sure what you'll see with a multicast stream.

Comment: @SunilD. May be you can add your comments in a combined answer as it seems that monitoring MulticastInformation is only way to go with this . It was a nice discussion with you !

Comment: I'm about to jump on a plane, and I don't think I can give an appropriate answer to this question on my phone. I think it would be useful if you answered the question with the exact stats/properties you used in your solution. It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question and accept it. You'll be able to provide better details which will be useful to anyone else going down this path. Questions like this are why I keep coming back to Stack Overflow, you never know what you're going to learn :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to detect this failure , will be putting a monitor to watch stream .